# GIT альтернатива Rebase

Tags: git, github, gitlab

альтернатива Rebase в случае, если перетащить нужно только 1 коммит
правильно ли я понимаю
git cherry-pick

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, `rebase` перемещает комиты, а `cherry-pick` их копирует. Альтернатива ли? Зависит от поставленной цели.

Comment: В журнале `rebase -i`, если вчитаться, команда `pick` как раз делает `cherry-pick` коммита на новое основание. Так что да, они делают похожие вещи. Но, как верно отмечает @LEQADA, с ветками происходят разные вещи.